# i want use jsoup to grab news on my android app

Tags: android, jsoup

I have a problem that I want to use jsoup to grab news but always fail.
this is news website.
https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/

this is my picture .  which I circle is I wanted data.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KJAyOSdHO8APPD6_A9MjxkoFjekcQLXt

but no matter what I do. it always get wrong data or empty.
this is my program.

```
public class News extends AppCompatActivity {
Button ok;
private static final String url ="https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.news);
ok=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ok);
ok.setOnClickListener(okbtn);
}
private Button.OnClickListener okbtn=new Button.OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v){
try{
Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url).execute();
String body = response.body();
Document data = Jsoup.parse(body);//visible-phone print_hide
Elements country=data.select("main");
Elements main=data.select("div[id=module module--news-main index-main]");

for(Element e1: country)
{
mytoast(e1+"");
}
}
catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace() ;}
}
};
private void mytoast(String str)
{
Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
toast.show();
}
}
```

please help me 
thanks

Comment: I would really advise against this.  Using jsoup is inherently fragile, the data is not meant for automated parsing.  Minor changes to formatting will break things.  I advise you to find a newsfeed that posts in a more parsable format, preferably via an API.  An RSS feed would work well too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to see it's HTML first.

**If you can't see it, you don't use jsoup**.

There's a small hint in its comment:

> このページではJavaScriptを使用しています
>
> =>This is generated by JavaScript

If it's generated, you can't find it from Jsoup.

In this case, I'll use Chrome's tool to monitor the XHR tab

[image: GUIDE]

Look into each XHR request, and find the most possible one,

for example, I see this

`https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/json16/syuyo.json?_=1559183885640`

A part of the response:

```
"id":"193411",
"title":"三菱ＵＦＪ銀行 新規口座は原則デジタル通帳に",
"pubDate":"Thu, 30 May 2019 04:03:11 +0900",
"cate":"5",
...
"id":"193437",
"title":"エアレース世界選手権 今季限りで終了",
"pubDate":"Thu, 30 May 2019 09:40:37 +0900",
```

So this is exactly what you want. It comes from another link!

You don't need Jsoup, just HttpGet the link

`https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/json16/syuyo.json?_=1559183885640`

And I think the numbers looks like UnixTime,

So I check the current time is : 1559184830782, that's it.

Just use that link as API and `time` as parameter.

Comment: hi wesely:  when I open this web .it show this not normal text .       {
"link":"html\/20190530\/k10011934291000.html",
"title":"\u300C\u6DF1\u3044\u60B2\u3057\u307F\u306B\u6253\u3061\u3072\u3057\u304C\u308C\u300D\u72A0\u7272\u306E\u5C0F\uFF16\u5973\u5150\u4E21\u89AA\u304C\u30B3\u30E1\u30F3\u30C8"
},

Comment: That's utf-8 format, find some utf-8 translator, and than you'll see :" "title":"「深い悲しみに打ちひしがれ」犠牲の小６女児両親がコメント" (R.I.P.)

Comment: for example : https://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php (use decode unicode)

Comment: @kyo if that helps, can you please chose me as the accepted answer ? :)